# Why FMX.TWebBrowser cannot be used in desktop applications as per DelphiDocs?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-10.1-berlin

The [TWebBrowser documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser) mentions that

> Note: TWebBrowser is a mobile component. It cannot be used in
>   FireMonkey desktop applications.

Why this restriction? On Windows `TWebBrowser` defaults to Internet Explorer and works fine. Is the wiki wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at the DocWiki article for the [XE7 version](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser).  The [Berlin version](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser) says:

> The TWebBrowser component is available on all Supported Target Platforms.

This [change was made in XE8](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/What%27s_New#Desktop_Web_Browsers):

> FireMonkey now supports the use of the TWebBrowser component on desktop platforms (Windows and Mac OS X). Previously, TWebBrowser supported only the mobile platforms (Android and iOS). All the basic functions of the Web browser are available (such as navigate to URL, go back, go forward, and so on).